# C# foreach string with commas

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
string[] neededFiles = {
                           "file1.exe",
                           "fille2.exe"
                       };
for (int file = 0; file != neededFiles.Length; file++)
{
    if (!File.Exists(neededFiles[file]))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("App can't find this file - " + neededFiles[file]);
        return;
    }
}
```

Now when I launch my app it prints :

> App can't find this file - file1.exe
>
> App can't find this file - file2.exe

It's ok, but I wan't something like that:

> App can't find this(-these) file(-files) - file1.exe, file2.exe

With what function / how can I do it? Is it possible? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

```
// using System.IO;
// using System.Windows.Forms;
// using System.Collections.Generics;
// using System.Linq;
IEnumerable<string> notFound = neededFiles.Where(f => !File.Exists(f));
if (notFound.Any())
    MessageBox.Show(
        string.Format(notFound.Count() > 1 ?
            "App can't find these files - {0}" :
            "App can't find this file - {0}",
        string.Join(", ", notFound)));
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but i have error here (red underlined text): **string.Join(notFound, ", "));** what's wrong here?

Comment: @Evaldas777 I fixed it. Sorry about that. I accidentally swapped the parameters. Please try my answer again now.

Comment: This is a beautiful answer.  Concise, readable.  It even accounts for the "this" / "these" distinction.  Nice.

Comment: @Evaldas777 Are you sure? Just copy/paste my entire answer right after your `string[] neededFiles = { " file1.exe", "file2.exe" };` line. It should work.

Comment: My code:
`string[] neededFiles = { " file1.exe", "file2.exe" };
                                IEnumerable<string> notFound = neededFiles.Where(f => !File.Exists(f));
                                if (notFound.Any())
                                    MessageBox.Show(
                                        string.Format(notFound.Count() > 1 ?
                                            "App can't find these files - {0}" :
                                            "App can't find this file - {0}",
                                        string.Join(", ", notFound)));` Not work :/

Comment: @Evaldas777 I just copy/pasted that code into a new Winforms project, and there are no errors. Can you tell me what error you're getting? What does it say?

Comment: maybe I have error because I haven't got needed "using xxx" code?

Comment: @Evaldas777 Try adding my "using" statements that I just added to my answer.

Comment: Hmm, I have thes using statements, whats wrong? :((

Comment: @Evaldas777 I don't know. Please tell me the exact error message and what the red squiggly lines are beneath. For example, if I remove my `using System.IO` I get an error on `File` saying `The name 'File' does not exist in the current context`. Please tell me what your errors say.

Comment: @Jashaszun, I have these errors:
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string> to string [] cannot

Comment: @Jashaszun heh I'm fixed, Please change your code "string.Join(", ", **notFound**)));" to "string.Join(", ", **neededFiles**)));"

Comment: @Evaldas777 I assumed, based on your question, that you only want to print the files that are needed but not found. If so, my answer should work perfectly. If not, then yes, you can change `notFound` to `neededFiles` in the join.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    string[] neededFiles = {
                                "file1.exe",
                                "fille2.exe"
                           };

    string msg = string.Empty;
    for (int file = 0; file != neededFiles.Length; file++)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(neededFiles[file]))
        {
           msg += neededFiles[file]+" ";
        }
    }
    MessageBox.Show(" App can't find this(-these) file(-files) - " + msg);
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, but I wan't to fix @Jashaszun code, I think him code better than your ;)